# SvelteKit: Folder routes like routes/pagename/index.svelte don't work. Only file routes like routes/pagename.svelte get resolved

Tags: sveltekit

I have updated sveltekit from 1.0.0-287 to 1.0.0-295, and since then nested folder routes cannot be resolved (page not found).

The following file structure works fine...

```
src
|__routes
   |__pagename.svelte
```

But nested folder routes cannot be found...

```
src
|__routes
   |__pagename
      |__index.svelte
```

Edit: picture added
[image]

Comment: Update: this problem happens only when I navigate to a page from a link in the Navigation Bar. If I type the page name in the address bar manually, then it works fine

Comment: What does the link that you use to navigate to the page look like?

Comment: nothing special: http://localhost:8080/pagename. That's weird - because if I click on a link in the navbar it changes route in the address bar but renders the page as not found. And if after that I click on the browser's refresh button it renders and shows the requested page.

Comment: If I right-click on the link in the navbar and select to open it in the tab, then it also opens the page normally

Comment: I meant how did you make the page navigate to a different route, what functions do you use

Comment: And is the link has a prefetch in it or did you make your route static

Comment: I tried both: placed <a href='/pagename'> tag directly on a navbar, and put a button with goto navigation - <button on:click={ () => goto('/pagename') }>
In both cases routing in the address bar works correctly - changes address to http://localhost:8080/pagename, but browser shows 'page not found'. And after reloading the page (with the same address -http://localhost:8080/pagename ) it shows correct page

Comment: and to remember that this behavior happens only when my target page is in the nested folder. It doesn't happen if the page is directly in the routes folder

Comment: Have you tried this using multiple browsers? and by any chance do you have this project uploaded in GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Found the source of the problem.
In my routes folder I have [...path] folder containing svelte component which renders custom "Page not found" page. Typically, if I route to a non-existent page, it should redirect to the [...path] folder ("not found" page). At least it worked this way before an update. Now, sveltekit redirects all my routes to this folder. Apparently, after an update, something got changed.